# Can't get firestore doc using admin sdk

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've got a little test files that tries to get a firestore doc using the admin sdk.  I keep getting the error `TypeError: admin.firestore(...).collection(...).doc(...).then is not a function`

I'm serving/testing locally.  What am I doing wrong?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(functions.config().cert),
  databaseURL: functions.config().databaseURL
});

const getMessage = () => {
  return admin.firestore().collection('messages').doc('1DwcY72Jt4Wj9QuZ8TyR').then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => {
    return err
  })
}

getMessage();
```

Answer (score 9):

I think you need to perform some action on the document you want. Try `.get()`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document

So for you:

```
return admin
  .firestore()
  .collection('messages')
  .doc('1DwcY72Jt4Wj9QuZ8TyR')
  .get()
  .then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => {
```

Comment: all I get as a response is `{
    "code": "MODULE_NOT_FOUND"
}`

Comment: The link you give defaults to Web version 9 SDK. For admin API, click 'Node.js' or use this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#node.js_1

Answer (score 1):

You've got two things wrong here.

You can't run arbitrary code or scripts in Cloud Functions.  You need to declare a function that will get triggered when something happens in your project.  As it stands now, you've declared no triggers.  Are you trying to write an [HTTP trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events)?  A [Firestore trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events)?  Read the documentation and use the `firebase-functions` module to declare one.

Second, your code is not actually fetching any documents.  All you have right now is a DocumentReference that points to a document:

```
admin.firestore().collection('messages').doc('1DwcY72Jt4Wj9QuZ8TyR')
```

At the very least, you'll need to call get() on that to actually fetch the document, then deal with the promise it returns.